# Developing a web App in Spring Tool Suit

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have developed a dynamic web application in spring tool suit using Spring MVC architecture. I added the required jars to develop the application and even installed the tomcat 7.0 to make the application run on server. However, when I try to run the application on server I am unable to run the Application. I am unable to understand what may be the reason. I am also getting an error that the dispatcher servlet is not found.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:529)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:511)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5493)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The jars are:

```
commons-logging-api-1.1.1
jstl-1.1.2 (1)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xdocreport-1.0.4
org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.5.RELEASE
servlet-api-2.5
spring-asm-3.0.7.RELEASE
spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE
spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE
spring-core-4.0.6.RELEASE
spring-expression-4.0.6.RELEASE
spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE
spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE
```

Comment: Is `spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE` in your war file under `WEB-INF/lib` or in tomcat `lib` directory?

Comment: It is under Web-inf/lib folder

Comment: You should not need `org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.5.RELEASE` or `servlet-api-2.5`. `spring-asm-3.0.7.RELEASE` is already in spring-core. Remove these.

Comment: I even tried removing the jar files you specified.

Comment: For starters stop mixing 4! (3.0.5, 3.0.7, 3.1.1 and 4.0.6) different versions of spring.. Use maven (or another dependency management tool) to get your dependencies don't try to figure out things yourself.